# Vue.js - How to make a numbered input list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using **Vue.js Version 2.0**

I have this code, which produces a list from an array. It inserts each array item inside an input field:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="portEditTab2">
<div v-for="list in nameList">
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label"
               for="nameList">1</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input v-bind:value=list.nameList
                   type="text"
                   id="nameList">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my vue instance:

```
var portEditTab = new Vue({
    el: '#portEditTab2',
    data: {
        nameList: []
    }
});
```

As this code stand right now, if, for example, 'list.nameList' has 3 items in its array, it will put each of the 3 items in their own input fields.

What I want to be able to do is put a label next to each input field, and I just want it to be numbers going from 1 to however many input fields their are.

Currently, the `<label>` field is `1`. As it stands, each input field will have a `1` as it's label. I would like it so that the `<label>` numbers go up by 1, so that the labels are, for example, `1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Inside v-for blocks we have full access to parent scope properties. **v-for also supports an optional second argument for the
>   index of the current item**.

http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for

```
<div v-for="(list, index) in nameList">
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label"
               for="nameList">{{ index }}</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input v-bind:value=list.nameList
                   type="text"
                   id="nameList">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a `key` with `v-for`. See more in vue.js docs https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#key

Try after updating your code to following.

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="portEditTab2">
<div v-for="list in nameList" :key="list.id">
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label"
               for="nameList">{{list.id}}</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input v-bind:value=list.nameList
                   type="text"
                   id="nameList">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```